# CSS Parallelogram-Cut Border Pattern

Tags: html, css

I would like insight as to whether or not it is possible to develop a border pattern like the one displayed [here](http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1872044/241546264/stock-vector-vintage-postcard-vector-design-241546264.jpg) through CSS code. I've considered making the pattern through a Photoshop-like program and then setting the background of the border to the url of the photoshop-made pattern. How I run into browser compatibility issues if I wish to pursue this through coding?

Comment: `border-image` would indeed be the way to go. [Compatibility is actually pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image) assuming people don't ignore Windows Update (everyone *should* be on IE11 if they're using IE, but, well...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Able to make a pretty similar border using straight css.

First, in before, generated a box with 3 striped lines- one red, one blue, one beige. Also added the beige border to this.

Then, in the :after pseudo element, just gave the box a beige background (probably could look better with a gradient background too).

Check it out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

p.box:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    hsl(60, 56%, 81%) 0px,
    hsl(60, 56%, 81%) 4px,
    red 5px,
    red 14px,
    hsl(60, 56%, 81%) 15px,
    hsl(60, 56%, 81%) 20px,
    hsla(247, 83%, 37%, 1) 21px,
    hsla(247, 83%, 37%, 1) 30px
  ),
  linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(48, 26, 255, 1),
    rgba(85, 66, 255, 1) 
  );
  border: 5px solid hsl(60, 56%, 81%);
}

p.box:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -.5%;
  bottom: -2.5%;
  background: hsl(60, 56%, 81%);
  z-index: -1;
  height: 97%;
  width: 97%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="box"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whoa, fantastic improvision!